# Example 4 in Section 9 Chapter 2 of Analysis on manifolds, J. R. Munkres

Tags: real-analysis, implicit-differentiation

The fourth example listed in Section 9 of Chapter 2 of *Analysis on manifolds* (1991, I don't if there are more editions) is about a particular case of the implicit function theorem. The aim of this example is to show that the function you find is unique in a neighborhood but may not be if you consider a larger one. Then, the author defines $f(x,y)=y^2-x^4$ and study the thesis of the theorem around the point $(1,2)$. Here it comes the first problem, because $f(1,2)\neq 0$, so I guess the correct $f$ is

$$f(x,y)=y^2-4x^4.$$

Now, Munkres solves for $y$:

$$y=g(x)=2x^2$$.

The function $g$ is not computed explicitly actually, but certainly $f(x,g(x))=0$ and $g(1)=2$.

Now he draws the following picture:

[image]

From this picture I conclude that, when you consider the origin, you are including other possible solutions, namely, the above $g$ and also

$$
z(x)=\begin{cases}
2x^2, & x\geq 0 \\\
-2x^2, & x<0 .
\end{cases}
$$

However, the function $f$ is $C^\infty$ so, in particular it is $C^3$. However, the above function is not, and the theorem ensures you that it will be. Hence the $z$ is not the the one that the theorem provides. And even if it is not $z$ the function Munkres is thinking about, I cannot imagine how you can paste $x^2$ smoothly to get different ones.

Then, my question is: Is there some detail I am misunderstanding or is it actually a mistake?

Thanks

Comment: I don't understand the question. The theorem gives you a condition that would guarantee $z$ is nice. The theorem cannot make $z$ nice if it is not nice to begin with.

Comment: No no. The $z$ is the function I guess Munkres refers to. But you don't need it. My question is: why when you include the origin the theorem is not valid? One function is the parabola. But what's the other?

Comment: @Dog_69 do you mean "I guess the correct $f$ is $f(x,y) = y^2-4x^4$" instead of $y^2-4x^2$?

Comment: @mathworker Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are actually asking if there is a mistake in mathematics, rather than a mistake in Munkres. Indeed, forget about what Munkres is saying, look at the graph of $f(x,y) = y^2-4x^4$ and note that for $g(x) = 2x^2$ for $x \ge 0$ and $g(x) = -2x^2$ for $x < 0$, it holds that $f(x,g(x)) = 0$ and $g(1) = 2$, but $g$ is not $C^\infty$, supposedly contradicting the implicit function theorem.

It turns out that there is no mistake in mathematics and that there is some detail you are misunderstanding.

The implicit function theorem says that there exists a neighborhood of $1$ for which there is a unique continuous function $h$ satisfying $h(1) = 2$ and $f(x,h(x)) = 0$, and it turns out that this unique function $h$ is $C^\infty$. [**The implicit function theorem does not directly say there is a unique $C^\infty$ function $h$, though it of course implies there is.**] However, there is no comment about the uniqueness or smoothness of a $g$ satisfying $g(1) = 2$ and $f(x,g(x)) = 0$ in other neighborhoods! And this is what Munkres is demonstrating. The lack of uniqueness comes from the fact that also $h(x) \equiv 2x^2$ (for $x \ge 0$ and $x < 0$) also satisfies $h(1) = 2$ and $f(x,h(x)) = 0$, and the lack of smoothness comes from the fact (that you noted) that $g$ is not even $C^3$.

Comment: I don't agree with your first paragraph. The fact that your $g$ (my $z$) does not satisfy the implicit function theorem does not mean it is false. $g$ is not the function the theorem is talking about, but that does not imply that there is no $h$ satisfy the conditions. In fact your $h$ does. My point, what I think is that taking $g$ is not a good choice for the counterexample because it is not $C^\infty$. What I really mean is that even if you consider a larger neighborhood of $1$, in this particular case, the function the theorem refers to seems to be unique.

Comment: I expected that, when you would include the origin, you would have another smooth function satisfying the same conditions. And it's because $g$ is not $C^\infty$ why I say that it is not a counterexample from my point of view. But no, the fact that $g$ not be smooth does not imply that the theorem is wrong. It was not my intentention to say that.

Comment: @Dog_69 no. the implicit function theorem is not saying "there is a unique $C^\infty$ function $h$ with $h(1) = 2$ and $f(x,h(x)) = 0$". It rather says "there is a unique continuous function $h$ with $h(1) = 2$ and $f(x,h(x)) = 0$. It happens that this $h$ is $C^\infty$". I made this clear in my answer.

Comment: Yes, it's true. I omitted that subtle but really important detail, sorry. In order to accept your answer, I would like you to change the first paragraph, because I never claimed that the implicit function theorem was contradicted. Instead, you can emphasise (even more) the difference between what the theorem says ''there is a unique continuous function $h$ with $h(1)=$2 and $f(x,h(x))=0$. It happens that this $h$ is C^\infty$'' and what I was saying "there is a unique $C^\infty$ function h with $h(1)=2 and f(x,h(x))=0$".

Comment: @Dog_69 I don't think you actually thought the implicit function theorem was wrong. I used the first paragraph to emphasize the fact that you didn't think there was a mistake with what Munkres was saying but rather that there was something you were missing about the implicit function theorem. I don't see what's wrong with the first paragraph. Feel free to correct me though.

Comment: Well... I imagined there was something that I was misunderstanding, although I didn't think it were about the theorem but about the example. If that is what you wanted to say in the first paragraph is okay then.

Comment: Yes, of course. I have already accepted your answer. Thanks for the clarifications

Comment: @Dog_69 No problem. I didn't realize this subtlety of the implicit function theorem until your question, so thank you as well.

Comment: I thought I warded your answer with the bounty when acceptint but it seems that not. I should have already thine though, sorry for the delay.

Comment: @Dog_69 I missed rent by a week!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is some misunderstanding:

**First:** Implicit Function Theorem state that one variable can be expressed as a unique function over other variables. In this case $y=g(x)$, so there is no $f$ or $z$ can  explain by this theorem! Just a relation between variables.

**Second:** The example and its figure try to show that the uniqueness of this relation is not guaranteed if you large your neighbourhood. In this case theorem fails and no valid relation can be expressed any more. In fact when $x$ reaches $0$, by $y=g(x)=2x^2$ we get $y=0$ too. But in this case $\partial f / \partial y$ also become $0$, that result in theorem criteria fails, so after that any relation no more remain valid. The figure is $yx$-axis and shows both two function that claims express $y$ over $x$. Don't confuse it by graph of $f$.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your answer. I know that is the aim of the example. What I say is that I think it does not achieve its goal. And I don't know what you mean by "there is no f can explain by this theorem". I mean, the hypothesis of the Implicit Function Theorem starts considering an $f$. And $z$ in the case is just another possible function satisfying the same conditions that the $g$ the theorem provides.

Comment: I, mistakenly, think you use $z$ as third dimension and equal to $f$. But about the aim of example, I add some clearance to my answer.

Comment: Okey, now I see what you mean. And although the Implicit Function Theorem only requires $Df$ to be non-vanishing at $(a,b)$, the proof uses the Inverse Function Theorem, which assumes $Df\neq 0$ in a neighbourhood. Then, when $Df$ vanishes, the Implicit Function Theorem may not be true. But I don't understand the picture yet. At the origin $Df$ vanishes OK. But why is this related to the other parabola he draws?

Comment: I add an explanation to my answer, hope address you.

Comment: The Munkre's version doesn't say anything about 1-1, so I don't agree with you yet...